# How convert list to json based on same key value in django

Tags: python, django

How convert list to  json based on same key value in django

My django list (my question)

```
{'include_product_id[x_734652]': ['1'], 
'product_name[x_734652]': ['Test_1'],
'product_qty[x_734652]': ['1'], 
'product_price[x_734652]': ['10'],
'total_amount[x_734652]': ['10'], 

'include_product_id[x_332559]': ['2'], 
'product_name[x_332559]': ['Test_2'], 
'product_qty[x_332559]': ['10'], 
'product_price[x_332559]': ['10'], 
'total_amount[x_332559]': ['100']}
```

I need result like that

```
 [{'include_product_id': 1,
   'product_name': Test_1, 
   'product_qty': 1,
   'product_price': 1, 
   'total_amount': 10,
  },
  {'include_product_id': 2,
   'product_name': Test_2, 
   'product_qty': 10,
   'product_price': 10, 
   'total_amount': 100,
  }]
```

Comment: How is it related to Django?

Comment: do a json.load(myJson) and then loop it on a for loop by key and remove the numbers from keys then loop it again and get first child from array on the result value and convert it to number and in the case of the Test_1 and Test_2 you need to change it to string and then getattr(myTestClass, 'Test_1')

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the items and read the `x_<digits>` part to know for which dict it should go:

```
x = {}

for key, value in data.items():
    x_id_index = key.rindex("[")
    x_id = key[x_id_index+1:-1]
    x_dict = x.setdefault(x_id, {})
    x_dict[key[:x_id_index]] = value[0]

x_values = list(x.values())

print(x_values)
```

**Output** (pretty printed)

```
[
    {
        "include_product_id": "1",
        "product_name": "Test_1",
        "product_qty": "1",
        "product_price": "10",
        "total_amount": "10"
    },
    {
        "include_product_id": "2",
        "product_name": "Test_2",
        "product_qty": "10",
        "product_price": "10",
        "total_amount": "100"
    }
]
```